# Cartoon episode where a character's prosthetic arm turns him evil

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember watching an episode of a cartoon on TV sometime between 2009 and 2013. I don't remember what channel I was watching it on, but it was almost certainly a rerun.

In it, a character who was missing an arm (or perhaps just a hand) had a prosthetic arm given to him by one of the other characters. The arm then for some reason turned him evil, with the end of the episode having the characters removing the prosthetic from him (and maybe destroying or sealing it).

Does anyone know the name of this show?

Comment: I don't know which show, but it seems to be a parody of the movie  Idle Hands : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_Hands

Comment: @A.bakker - That trope predates Idle Hands (in film) by about a hundred years; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilHand

Comment: @John - What you're describing is a pretty common trope. Can you give any additional detail? You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Adventure Time?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be an episode of Venture Brothers centered around Billy Quizboy who has a prosthetic hand? Although the actual origins of his prosthetic hand are not revealed until later in the series there is an early episode where different characters recount how they believe he got his hand and the various different scenarios around it are shown as a series of vignettes which encompass various tropes such as the evil limb.

[image: Billy Quizboy]